# Hi im trying to read Response

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I am working on making Bookmarklet.

I'm trying to get stat : fail after my submit function finish: If stat is pass or fail. Will then make a decision according to that.

I have idea about JSON with Ajax but in this we don't have JSON.

Json will look something like this.

```
function Check(Content) {
    response = JSON.parse(Content);
    Result = response.stat;
    if (Result == ok) {
        Gotit();
    } else {
        Fail();
    };
};
```

So any idea how it can be read as it has no JSON?

[image]

Comment: please provide the response in the question and not as an image link.

Answer (score 0):

If JSON is not defined you have to include the json2 library in your page before using it, the

[**lib is here**](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)

Comment: `JSON` is supported by all major browsers since IE8. I don't think this is the issue the asker is facing...

Answer (score 0):

the issue seems to be that the response JSON is the first element of an array(Content). Did you try

```
response = JSON.parse(Content[0])
```